# Different behavior between T.Type & [T.Type]

Tags: swift, uitableview, generics, metatype

I am using generics func to improve tableView cells as below;

```
public func registerNib<T: UITableViewCell>(_:T.Type) {
    print("Registering.....")
    print(T.self)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: T.self), bundle: nil)
    register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: T.self))
}
```

And I wrote two func to register cell, one for single cell and one for multiple cells.

> //Single Cell Register

```
func setup<T: UITableViewCell>(cell:T.Type) {
   print(cell)
   tableView.registerNib(cell)
   self.setupParameters(.....)
}
```

> //Multiple Cell Register

```
func setup<T: UITableViewCell>(cells:[T.Type]) {
   for cell in cells {
        print(cell)
        tableView.registerNib(cell)
    }
   self.setupParameters(.....)
}
```

For single cell implementation, you can call func as below and it will registerNib correctly.

```
self.baseTableView.setup(cell: CompetencyCell.self, rowHeight: 60)

**************
Output:
CompetencyCell
Registering...
CompetencyCell
```

But problem is occur with multiple implementation;

```
self.baseTableView.setup(cells: [CompetencyCell.self, BehaviorCell.self], rowHeight: 60)

**************
Output:
CompetencyCell
BehaviorCell
Registering...
UITableViewCell
UITableViewCell
```

I really wonder what is the reason, or what I miss? It looks like same behavior but when I want to pass T.Type value to RegisterNib method it turns to UITableViewCell and after some point of course I got crash because it could not find the cell.

Do you have any advice?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

When calling a generic function the generic type `T` represents a **single** static type.

`[T.Type]` is nonsensical because it declares an array of the **same** type specifier.

`T` doesn't mean `Any`!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you know any workaround? How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As described in vadian's answer, generic is not a good tool to use with Array containing multiple types of values.

You can try something like this:

```
extension UITableView {
    public func registerNib(_ type: UITableViewCell.Type) {
        print("Registering.....")
        print(type)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type), bundle: nil)
        register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: type))
    }
}
```

And this:

```
func setup(cells: [UITableViewCell.Type] /*, otherParams: ...*/) {
    for cell in cells {
        print(cell)
        tableView.registerNib(cell)
    }
    //self.setupParameters(.....)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It worked but I really want to know why is  generic is a bad for containing multiple types of values with Array?

Comment: @GöktuğAral, Swift infers generic type statically. So, with your definition `setup<T: UITableViewCell>(cells:[T.Type])`, Swift infers the type `T` statically at each call. What type do you think Swift infers `T`, when you call it like `setup(cells: [CompetencyCell.self, BehaviorCell.self])`. `T` needs to be some type which can represent both `CompetencyCell.self` and `BehaviorCell.self`, `T` is inferred as `UITableViewCell` as it is the common ancestor of them. Generic parameter does not change dynamically in runtime, it needs to be solved in compile time.